# schedule image post on facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am trying to schedule a photo on facebook page as page. When i try to schedule only message then it works but when i give the source of image then it gives error **Graph returned an error: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.**

```
$image = url().'/images/logo.png';

$data = [
'message' => 'new schedule 1',

'source' => $image,

'published' => 0,

'scheduled_publish_time' => $epochTime

];


$response = $fb->post('/949206005163395/feed', $data, $pageAccessToken);
```

Please help

Comment: if it says try again later then try again later

Answer (score 3):

Finally found an answer after researching for two days. Hope it will help someone else as well. 
**Solution : **

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $epochTime = strtotime("now +15 minute");
        $data = [
            'message' => 'Your message',
            'no_story' => 0,
            'link'=>'http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg',
            'picture'=>'http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg',
            'published' => 0,
            'scheduled_publish_time' => $epochTime
        ];
$response = $fb->post('/'.$post->page_id.'/feed', $data, $pageAccessToken);
```

You can also provide link by using link attribute.